# Leetcode 46: Choosing between two different ways to generate permutations?

Tags: python, algorithm, backtracking

I'm working on https://leetcode.com/problems/permutations/ and I'm trying to decide which approach for generating the permutations is more clear. The question is "Given an array nums of distinct integers, return all the possible permutations. You can return the answer in any order." I've got two different solutions below.

Solution 1

```py
def permute(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        results = []
        N = len(nums)
        def dfs(subset, permutation: List[int]):
            if len(subset) == N:
                results.append(subset.copy())
                return
            for i, num in enumerate(permutation):
                subset.append(num)
                dfs(subset, permutation[:i] + permutation[i+1:])
                # backtracking
                subset.pop()
        dfs([], nums)
        return results
```

Solution 2

```
def permute(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        results = []
        N = len(nums)
        def dfs(subset, permutation: List[int]):
            if len(subset) == N:
                results.append(subset.copy())
                return
            for i, num in enumerate(permutation):
                dfs(subset + [num], permutation[:i] + permutation[i+1:])
        dfs([], nums)
        return results
```

I believe in the first solution, when you append to a list in python (i.e append to the subset parameter), lists are pass by reference so each recursive call will share the same list. This is why we have to explicitly backtrack by popping from subset. However in the second solution when a list is passed to a recursive call with the syntax subset + [num], a copy of the list is passed to each recursive call so that's why we don't explicitly have to backtrack.

Can someone confirm if my assumptions are correct? Is one approach favored over another? I think the time and space complexities are identical for both approaches (O(N!) and O(N), respectively) where N = the number of elements in nums.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right that the first permute passes the same object (subset) in each recursive call.
And this is possible in first permute because lists are mutable, if you had a string to permute upon then you have to pass a copy because they are immutable.

And in the second permute a copy of subset is created. You can test it with the statement `print(id(subset))` at the beginning of `dfs` in each permute. You can observe that the statement prints same id in the first permute but not in the second permute.

To me even though both have same time complexity (*depends on what you do at the base condition - its O(N.N!) and not O(N!) because you are appending a copy of list to the result list* ), why do you want to create a copy of subset and place an entirely new object on stack when you can have the copy of object reference (not the object itself!) on the stack which consumes less memory. So I prefer first permute.

Comment: Total output size is O(N × N!), can't do that in O(N!).

Comment: The real work is done at the leaf nodes which are of the order of N! but then the permute is just adding the list to a list of lists which is O(1) well if its adding a copy its O(N). The time complexity is O(N!) if the work done at the leaf is O(1), otherwise its O(N*N!)

Comment: Well they *are* adding copies (as they need to, at least if they want to *return a list* of the permutations, as they do).

Comment: Yes if its adding a copy then its O(N*N!) as already stated and also updated my answer.

Comment: Ok. Wasn't updated yet. Btw, `itertools.permutations` actually *can* offer all permutations in O(N!) time if you let it (i.e., if you don't hold onto the reference of the previous permutation, so that itertools reuses it and only modifies it as needed).

Comment: thanks for the reply! @SomeDude I wasn't aware that lists are mutable in python but strings are immutable. I think in solution two, I can just append `subset` to results (since it's already a copy) instead of appending `subset.copy()`?

Comment: @VictorCui Yes you are right, you don't need subset.copy() in the second permute.